# How can I use regexreplace in Google Sheets with non-capturing groups?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've got the following text: "1-1/3 cups warm WATER 2 tablespoons white CHIA SEED MEAL 1/4 cup melted HONEY" 
 - I want to replace all spaces followed by a number with "ç" (1)

Usually regex in GSheets uses parenthesis to form capturing groups: when I use `=REGEXEXTRACT(B3,"(\s)\d")` I get a single space like I'm supposed to, but if I use `=REGEXREPLACE(B3,"(\s)\d","ç")` I get `Ingredients:ç-1/3 cups warm WATERç tablespoons white CHIA SEED MEALç/4 cup melted HONEY`

Does anybody know how to get Google to replace only the space, so that I get output like this: 
`Ingredients:ç1-1/3 cups warm WATERç2 tablespoons white CHIA SEED MEALç1/4 cup melted HONEY`? Thanks a ton!

(1) I use "ç" so that I can later use the "SPLIT" command to split on every "ç".

Comment: Using (?:...) for a non-capturing group like it says at https://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax and http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ didn't work:

Comment: I made a spreadsheet with the things I've tried that people can input their own code into: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S6PK0Xi-edSzgHO7uQmeRocGE1j5gM_RbX86NvH1Xcw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My way of approaching this would be to use back-references in the third argument:

`=REGEXREPLACE(C3,"\s(\d)","ç$1")`